# cordova-plugin-sms exec proxy not found

Tags: javascript, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins, mobile-application

Hello I'm new in App development and I'm using cordova sms plugin to be able to auto send sms on button press. I followed the instructions carefully in this link https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-sms but it keeps saying `exec proxy not found::SMS::sendSMS`

Here's my code:

```
function sendSMS() {
        var sendto = "+1234";
        var textmsg = "MESSAGE";
        if(sendto.indexOf(";") >=0) {
            sendto = sendto.split(";");
            for(i in sendto) {
                sendto[i] = sendto[i].trim();
            }
        }
        if(SMS) SMS.sendSMS(sendto, textmsg, 
        function()
        {
         alert('Success');
        }, 
        function(str)
        {
          alert(str);
        });
}
```

Comment: please specify for which platform you working with?

Comment: I'm working with android and ios platform

Comment: yes but this plugin is not support by IOS. You need to test it in android

Comment: yes i already tested it in anrdoid but nothings happening

Comment: on a real device? not simulator

Comment: yes on a real device via phonegap client appliation